# How to dot product 3d numpy array rows into another 3d array rows and get a 3d array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I have numpy arrays `a` of shape `(3, 4, 2)` and `b` of shape `(3, 2, 5)`. And I want the product of each row of `a` (of shape `(4, 2)`) by each row of `b` (of shape `(2, 5)`) and the result be a 3d array of shape `(3, 4, 5)`.

Of course I don't want to use `for` loop otherwise I could iterate over rows.

Comment: Look at `np.matmul` instead.  Or `np.einsum`.

Comment: Wow, I did not know about `matmul`. This is exactly what I was looking for. Could you please answer it below so I can close this question.